# Right way to add a field to be used as a filter in Views with ranges?

Tags: views

I need to add a field to a content type which is going to used as a exposed filter in Views.In this filter the visitor will see ranges. I've done this in the past and ended creating 2 fields to set both limits of a range. I need to remake this and I think this can be done in a smarter way.

What I need is:

1) create the content type: **flat**

2) add the field **price** to the content type **flat**

3) create a view **Flats**

4) create a **exposed filter** to filter by the field price but using ranges, e.g: "From 100 000 to 200 000", "From 200 001 to 300 000" and so on. I need these options to be a Select dropdown list.

Then my questions are:

- about point 2): I would create a integer type field for this, is this right and enough?
- about point 4): How do I do to create the ranges that I need? Maybe a module for this?

Answer (score 0):

This module might help: [Views Contextual Range Filter](https://drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter)

Module Page Description:

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds
>   the option to contextually filter not just by a single value, but also
>   by range. Numeric, alphabetical (string) and list ranges are all
>   supported. Node ids, user ids and even taxonomy term ids are all
>   special cases of numbers so will work also. Range-filtering on the
>   "created" (posted) and "updated" (last modified) node properties is
>   also supported, provided you use the correct format as dictated by
>   Views. So, YYYYMMDD for full dates or one of the shorter formats, i.e.
>   year+month, year-only, month-only, week-only or day-only. You may use
>   the OR operator (i.e. +) and the negate operator. You negate by
>   ticking the "Exclude" box on the Views Contextual filter configuration
>   panel, in the "More" section.